# Docker CodeIgniter MariaDb Connection Refused

Tags: mysql, docker, codeigniter, docker-compose

Im new to docker and trying to deploy my script on docker container locally on my machine. but the issue is I am unable to connect to my database and when ever I query database I get error

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

I have tried solution by replacing  the `hostname => 'localhost'` with `127.0.0.1:3306` as I can see in my docker ps service but I am unable to connect.

**Docker Compose file:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    image: 'bitnami/codeigniter:3'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      restart: always
      ports:
          - 8080:80
      volumes:
          - /sessions
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: mariadb
```

[image: running container images]

I also tried to upgrade **mariadb:latest** but it didn't work.

**Database.php**

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '127.0.0.1:3306',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'notification_task',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**Edited:**

I have also verified my sql server is running by accessing it through shell and **docker exec**. but its not accessible thorugh codeigniter

Comment: specify the ports for mariadb in your compose file and it would be helpful to share your connection string.

Comment: tried but didnt work. its by default running on 3306 port

Comment: edited with database.php

Comment: Are the two containers running on the same network and if yes, replace ```'127.0.0.1``` with that IP.

You can use ```docker network inspect``` to get the IP mariadb is running on

Comment: @MargachChris thanks for the comment i have checked it its on the same network   `0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp`  after adding port to maria db

Comment: thanks @MargachChris this really helped alot I have checked that my all services are on the same network so I specified localhost and 12.0.0.1 with ports but didn't work as soon as i used my ip address it worked. thanks once again but I am still unable to get why it didnt work with local host and 127.0.0.1

Comment: Your welcome and the reason why localhost does not work is that the 2 containers are not sharing the 127.0.0.1 Ip and hence can't be reached on local host.

You can also check your host file on your machine to make sure localhost points to 127.0.0.1